# In Tablesorter, setting different values to the dropdown options of a column filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm using Tablesorter to display a table and I have a column with a dropdown filter with several options. Something like this:

```
widgetOptions : {
    filter_functions: {
        4: {
            users_all : function() {},
            users_collaborators : function() {},
            users_clients : function() {}
        }
    }
}
```

All those three values (users_all, users_collaborators and users_clients) are variables but they're being displayed as strings.

Is there any way to display the variables' content?

**UPDATE 1**

What I'm trying to do is to display the options in one language or another (nothing to do with the table).

I've tried changing the select options through filter_selectSource like this:

```
widgetOptions: {
    filter_selectSource: {
        4 : [ 'Client', 'Collaborator' ]
    },
    filter_functions: {
        4 : true
    }
}
```

But it throws an error (Cannot read property 'format' of undefined) on jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js:1464

I'm populating the table through ajaxProcessing and I'm picking this filter just like any other:

```
ajaxUrl: '/users/table_users.php?page={page}&size={size}&{sortList:sort}&{filterList:filter}'
```

I tried setting up your demo myself and had no problem at all.

**ONCE RESOLVED IT LOOKS LIKE:**

```
widgetOptions : {
    filter_functions: {
        4: true
    },
    filter_selectSource: {
        4 : [ user_all, user_collaborators, user_clients ]
    }
}
```

And I've added the class `filter-select-nosort` to the header of that column in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do with the filter select?

You can change the select options using the [`filter_selectSource` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-selectsource) ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/63/))

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
        widgetOptions: {
            filter_selectSource: {
                1 : [ 'Client', 'Collaborator' ]
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That errors sounds like a parser isn't set for that column? Try adding "filter-select-nosort" to the header to prevent sorting the options.